# Link an Azure DevOps Work Item automatically using a git branch name

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to link Azure DevOps work items automatically using a specific Git branch name?

For example, if I have a work item with the id 123 in my team called ABC, is there a way to link automatically the 123 work item when I open a pull request from a branch called (or something similar):

```
feature/ABC-123-my-feature-work-item-title
```

I know it's possible in other popular project management tools, but I haven't found an example of doing the same thing without needing to add the work item manually on the pull request.

Comment: Pull requests are not a Git feature. They're a feature of various hosting sites. The way they work on each hosting site is slightly different, so pick which hosting site you're using and specify that (and adjust the tags in your question).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, as specified in my question's title, its content and its tag, I'm asking the question for Azure DevOps which is a Git hosting service. I have removed the git tag (even if it was suggested by StackOverflow when creating the question) because it seems it may cause confusion.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: No, but I don't use Azure DevOps anymore